# i have a error in pysnmp:caused by <class 'IndexError'>: pop from empty list

Tags: python

i have a error in pysnmp:caused by <class 'IndexError'>: pop from empty list

I am confused. I didn't do anything，But sometimes my code doesn't work

but sometimes

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../conpot/protocols/snmp/conpot_cmdrsp.py", line 170, in handleMgmtOperation
rspVarBinds = self.proxy.getRequest(snmp_version, oid, **user_info)
File "../conpot/protocols/snmp/snmp_proxy.py", line 65, in getRequest
ObjectIdentity(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 183, in getCmd
**kwargs):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 113, in getCmd
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 50, in runDispatcher
raise PySnmpError('poll error: %s' % ';'.join(format_exception(*exc_info())))
pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: poll error: Traceback (most recent call last):
; File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 46, in runDispatcher
use_poll=True, map=self.__sockMap, count=1)
; File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncore.py", line 207, in loop
poll_fun(timeout, map)
; File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncore.py", line 188, in poll2
readwrite(obj, flags)
; File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncore.py", line 123, in readwrite
obj.handle_error()
; File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncore.py", line 110, in readwrite
obj.handle_write_event()
; File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncore.py", line 442, in handle_write_event
self.handle_write()
; File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dgram/base.py", line 142, in handle_write
outgoingMessage, transportAddress = self.__outQueue.pop()
;IndexError: pop from empty list
caused by <class 'IndexError'>: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Could you please post some of your code that is causing the error? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is good that you posted the error message, but it is hard to help unless we can see the parts of the code that are causing the problem. Could you please add that?